# How can I have a deadline for an issue at Microsoft GitHub?

Tags: github

How can I set a deadline for issues at Microsoft Github?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not the most intuitive of interfaces, but in Github's Issues view for your project has a tab called Milestones.

With this feature you can set up a Milestone for your project (a release for instance) and set a due date for the milestone.

You can then go back to your list of issues or pull requests, select some and add them to a Milestone.

The Milestone can then track progress (number of issues or pull requests closed  divided by the total number assigned to the Milestone)

You can read more about this feature on the [Microsoft Github help pages](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-editing-milestones-for-issues-and-pull-requests/)

Comment: Hello Gavin, Thanks for your kind response, and thank you so much for the answer! This will help me a lot!

Comment: Milestones are not really meant for individual issues and server a different purpose: a date where a whole bunch of related issues gets fixed.
Issue dates should be dynamic and really represent due dates for activities on the issue, when to discuss the issue again etc.
GitLab does have that, sadly GitHub has still not managed to implement this.

Comment: Urgh this is so clunky of GitHub not to have per-issue deadlines. This question was asked such a long time ago and nothing has changed. Oh well. Everything else about GitHub is pretty awesome so I guess we should forgive them for this ;)

Comment: I know @JamesGeddes - but I guess I would prefer them to keep their focus on providing good tools for managing git repositories. I tend to use separate project management software such as [Taiga](https://www.taiga.io/) or Jira for this more fine-grained control.

Comment: @Gavin Jira is a good point - much love for Jira - and I do agree with you on the Dev tools. At the moment we are only using GitHub so it would be a "nice to have" but we can always move to Jira in the future.

Answer (score 6):

GitHub introduced a completely new way of [managing projects](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/creating-projects/creating-a-project) a little while ago.

Using the table view of a project, you can add custom fields of various types, including a [date type](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/understanding-fields/about-date-fields).

Click this 'plus' icon in the upper right of the table and select 'New field', then enter a name and pick the Date type for the new field.

[image: custom field menu] [image: custom field with date type]

Comment: I don't see this option.

Comment: Oh, it's a zoombug.

Comment: However, I don't see any way to (visually) set one item to be completed after/before the other.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can sort the table by any column, including the custom ones like the due date.

Comment: How to do """*task A followed by B (followed by C ... Z)*"""? Eg: A get salary, B buy the bottle *(C wait for car and buy all the milk, D wait a day and make the bread)*.

Comment: No idea if that's possible. It's also a very different requirement than the original question so I'd suggest to post it as a new one.